# Including Web Site Logo When Using AddThis Printer Friendly Option

Tags: addthis

I am using the AddThis share toolbar and have implemented the printer friendly option that strips out all of the extraneous items from the page (sidebars, nav, images, etc.). However, I want to include the web site logo when users partake in this option. Is there a way to tell the page to include the logo when someone uses the printer friendly option?

Answer (score 0):

To specify a custom image for your site, specify the following in the  section:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/mylogo.png"/>
```

If you're already specifying an icon but want to specify a different image, you can use the following:

```
<p class="print-yes" style="display:none"><img src="/mylogo.png">This is my tagline</p>
```

More information here:

http://support.printfriendly.com/customer/portal/articles/206478-add-your-logo-to-printed-page-and-pdf